# Retrieving relevant record from a relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am allowing user to search by type which is passed into a function:

```
public function typeSearch($type)
{
    $events = Event::where('type', $type)
        ->with('entities')
        ->get();
    return view('events.searchResultEvents', compact('events'));
}
```

Which works nearly as it's supposed to do, it does retrieve the entities but not the right entities for example:

Event id = 25, entity_id = 2 it retrieves: Entities id = 25 while it should be 2.

How can I change this so it retrieves the right record?

Example::

[image]

Looking at the image, Event is = 25 and entity_id = 1. entity_id is a foreign key which is linked to id on 'entities' table

From Relations we have 'entities' with id = 25, while it should be 1 as entity_id = 1

Event  model::

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use Searchable;

    public function entities()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entity', 'id');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
    }
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\DirtyEvent', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give example what is current output and What your expected output?

Comment: Currently i'm not clear with your  `Event id = 25, entity_id = 2 it retrieves: Entities id = 25 while it should be 2.` example

Comment: @YashvantsinhZala see my edit and let me know if that makes more sense please

Comment: can you show me how is your Event model?

Comment: sure see my edit @ArigiWiratama

Comment: It's seems your relation is one to one and there's entity (25) related with event 25, change relation in event to be 
`public function entities() { return $this->hasMany('App\Entities'); }` and check records now maybe you will find entity_id = 2 and entity_id = 25

Comment: thanks for suggestion @EMADIGA however it still gives me only entity_id = 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's problem in your relations method.

```php
public function entities()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Entity', 'id'); // Ithink you need to change it
}
```

Change that `'id'` in your second parameter to `'entity_id'`

```php
public function entities()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Entity', 'entity_id');
}
```

The second parameter is used like this, I don't know how to explain it in technical but here's an example:

```php
$event = Event::find(1); 
//this will return the events with id=1 and that data have entity_id=2

$entities = $event->entities;
//If you set the second parameter in your Event model to 'id', 
//this $entities variable contain the data from entities table with id=1, because your $event id=1

//But if you set the second parameter to 'entity_id'
//this $entities variable contain the data from entities with the id=2, because your $event entity_id=2
```

Comment: this is actually working but why? I thought the 2nd parameter is the one it links to so belongs to Entity->id and Entity hasMany Event->entity_id i thought that was the way

Comment: Um... the second parameter is used to specify the table foreign_key (if its belongsTo), also it can be used to specify target table foreign_key (if its hasOne/hasMany)